# Por que mi ciclo while nunca termina de ejecutar

Tags: sql

tengo un SP en el cual ejecuto un ciclo while, creo una tabla temporal la cual la lleno con datos de una tabla dependiendo a un ID, esta tabla me inserta 18 registros y necesito recorrerlos para ir insertando y actualizando cada registro pero nunca termina de ejecutarse, este es mi codigo, gracias por su ayuda.

```
WHILE EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM #AfiliadosProceso WHERE IdCaso = 0)
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 @CotizanteId = CotizanteId, 
                 @CotizanteTipoId = CotizanteTipoId 
                 FROM #AfiliadosProceso 
                 WHERE IdCaso = 0

    INSERT INTO dbo.trCaso(IdTipoCaso, FechaCaso, Estado, IdOrigenCaso, IdProcesoSiam,Usuario,Idmovilidad)
    VALUES (2, @FechaVar  /*CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),101)*/,1,1,0,'S2Automatico',0)                                

    SET @IdCaso = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    UPDATE #AfiliadosProceso SET IdCaso = @IdCaso 
           WHERE Cotizanteid = @CotizanteId 
           AND CotizanteTipoid = @CotizanteTipoId
END
```

Comment: Tu tabla trCaso contiene un campo de tipo IDENTITY para recuperar el valor que se inserto?

Comment: Si, el campo id es de tipo identy, deberia crear un campo de este tipo para la tabla #AfiliadosProceso?

Comment: No esa tabla esta bien como esta, podrias poner la estructura de tu tabla para hacer unas pruebas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @IdCaso INT,@CotizanteId INT,@CotizanteTipoId INT
```

--Simulando algunos insert

```
INSERT INTO #AfiliadosProceso(CotizanteID,CotizanteTipoId,IdCaso) VALUES(1,2,0),(2,3,0),(4,5,0),(5,6,0),(7,8,0)
--Seleccionamos para verificar que el IDCaso es 0
SELECT idcaso,* FROM #AfiliadosProceso
WHILE EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM #AfiliadosProceso WHERE IdCaso = 0)
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 @CotizanteId = CotizanteId, 
                 @CotizanteTipoId = CotizanteTipoId 
                 FROM #AfiliadosProceso 
                 WHERE IdCaso = 0

INSERT INTO dbo.trCaso(IdTipoCaso, Estado, IdOrigenCaso, IdProcesoSiam,Usuario,Idmovilidad)
VALUES (2  /*CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),101)*/,1,1,0,'S2Automatico',0)                                

SET @IdCaso = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
--Actualizamos
UPDATE #AfiliadosProceso SET IdCaso = @IdCaso 
       WHERE Cotizanteid = @CotizanteId 
       AND CotizanteTipoid = @CotizanteTipoId
END


SELECT * FROM  dbo.trCaso

SELECT IdCaso, * FROM #AfiliadosProceso
```

Observo que en tu tabla #AfiliadosProceso Tienes un campo ID ese campo no se si lo estas llenando de ser asi tambien te podrias apoyar de el para identificar en cual va, de lo contrario ejecute la consulta tal y como esta y si me funciona.

Si podrias dar mas detalles de como estas llenado la información podriamos llegar a una mejor solución de lo contrario te dejo esto como muestra de que si se sale del ciclo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Tabla temporal con el campo nuevo**

```
Create Table #AfiliadosProceso  
    (Id Int-->I.V.C. 1.0.2
    ,BeneficiarioTipoId Varchar(2)
    ,BeneficiarioId Varchar(20)-->F.V.C. 1.0.2
    ,CotizanteIdTr Varchar(20)
    ,CotizanteTipoIdTr Varchar(2)
    ,CotizanteId Varchar(20)
    ,CotizanteTipoId Varchar(2)
    ,Apellido1 Varchar(50)
    ,Apellido2 Varchar(50)
    ,Nombre Varchar(50)
    ,FechaNacimiento DateTime
    ,Sexo Varchar(2)
    ,IdAfiliado Int
    ,EsFonetico Int
    ,EsInexistente Int
    ,IdMovilidad Int
    ,Apellido1FoneticoRef Varchar(20)
    ,Apellido2FoneticoRef Varchar(20)
    ,NombresFoneticoRef Varchar(20)
    ,CotizanteIdRef Varchar(20)-->I.V.C. 1.0.2
    ,CotizanteTipoIdRef Varchar(2)-->F.V.C. 1.0.2
    ,IdControl Int
    ,CodigoCausal Int
    ,IdCaso Int
    ,IdAfiliadoCaso Int
    ,IdCarta Int
    ,FechaRadicacion DateTime
    ,FechaCompensacion DateTime
    ,Numero_Radicacion Varchar(200)
    ,IdARTipoCausal Varchar(10),
    IdToDelete INT IDENTITY(1,1));

--DECLARAR UNA variable para ayudarte a contar 
DECLARE @HelpID INT=1;

WHILE EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM #AfiliadosProceso WHERE IdCaso = 0 AND IdToDelete= @HelpID)--Agregar el AND IdToDelete= @HelpID
BEGIN

    SELECT TOP 1 @CotizanteId = CotizanteId, 
                 @CotizanteTipoId = CotizanteTipoId 
                 FROM #AfiliadosProceso 
                 WHERE IdCaso = 0

    INSERT INTO dbo.trCaso(IdTipoCaso, Estado, IdOrigenCaso, IdProcesoSiam,Usuario,Idmovilidad)
    VALUES (2  /*CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),101)*/,1,1,0,'S2Automatico',0)                                

    SET @IdCaso = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    UPDATE #AfiliadosProceso SET IdCaso = @IdCaso 
           WHERE Cotizanteid = @CotizanteId 
           AND CotizanteTipoid = @CotizanteTipoId
           --NUEVA LINEA
           AND IdToDelete=@HelpID
--Agregamos uno mas
SET @HelpID=@HelpID+1;
END
```

Comment: Hola, si tambien me funciona. el campo ID de la tabla #AfiliadosProceso  lo lleno de otra tabla que ya contiene registros, le doy un Insert into #AfiliadosProceso select (campos) from dbo.trAfiliadosPorCarta. El punto era no dejar que las variables CotizanteID y CotizanteTipoId estuvieran en null)

Comment: Podrias crear entonces otro que te sirva para mapear Uno llamado IDTodelete INT IDENTITY(1,1)
Y en el where podrias poner esa validacion te anexo en la respuesta el ejemplo

Comment: Me sirvió de mucha ayuda, gracias.

Comment: De nada.
Saludos